# Partial Proof of an inequality by Vasile Cirtoaje

Tags: inequality, induction, solution-verification, exponentiation, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Claim

We want to show [1]:

> > Let $0.36\leq x\leq 0.5$ and $1\leq k\leq n$ two naturals numbers with $n\geq 10^{10}$ then we have :
> > $$P(k)=(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}+x^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}\leq 1\quad (I)$$

Sketch\Partial (of) proof .

We use a form of the Young's inequality or weighted Am-Gm :

Let $a,b>0$ and $0<v<1$ then we have :

$$av+b(1-v)\geq a^vb^{1-v}$$

Taking account of this theorem and putting :

$a=(x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}$$\quad$$b=1$$\quad$$v=(2(1-x))^{\frac{-1}{n}}$ we get :

$$(x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k-1}{n}}}\leq (x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}(2(1-x))^{\frac{-1}{n}}+1-(2(1-x))^{\frac{-1}{n}}$$

Now the idea is to show :

Let $$(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k-1}{n}}}\leq 1-\Big((x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}(2(1-x))^{\frac{-1}{n}}+1-(2(1-x))^{\frac{-1}{n}}\Big)$$

Or :

$$(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k-1}{n}}}\leq (2(1-x))^{\frac{-1}{n}}(1-(x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}})$$

Or:
$$(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k-1}{n}}+\frac{1}{n}}+2^{\frac{-1}{n}}(x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}\leq 2^{\frac{-1}{n}}\quad (0)$$

Now we want to show that :

$$2^{\frac{-1}{n}}(x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}\leq (x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}\quad(1)$$

For that we need a lemma :

Lemma :

Let $0< x\leq 0.5$ and $1\leq k\leq n$ two naturals numbers then we have :

$$f(k)=\ln(x)((2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k-1}{n}}-(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}})\leq f(k+1)=\ln(x)((2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}-(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}})$$

It's true because it's equivalent to :

$$(2(1-x))^{\frac{k-1}{n}}((2(1-x))^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)^2\geq 0$$

So we have :

$$f(n)\geq f(k)$$

We can show also that on $x\in[0.36,0.5]$ :

$$f(k)\leq 0$$

Because we have  $x\in[0.36,0.5]$ :

$$p(x)=-\ln(x)((2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k-1}{n}})\geq 0$$

Is decreasing and :

$$t(x)=((2(1-x))^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)\geq 0$$

As the product of two positive decreasing function is a decreasing function remains to calculate the value around $x\simeq 0.36$ wich is equivalent to $(1)$

So we have from $(1)$ and $(0)$ we need to show :

$$ (x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}+(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k-1}{n}}+\frac{1}{n}}\leq 2^{\frac{-1}{n}}$$

But  we have $x \in[0.36,0.5]$:

$$(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k-1}{n}}+\frac{1}{n}}<(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}$$

It's true because it's equivalent to :

$$(2x)^{1+\frac{k-1}{n}}-(2x)^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}\geq 0\geq \frac{-1}{n}$$

So we need to prove $x\in[0.36,0.5-\varepsilon_n]$ with $\varepsilon_n>0$:

$$Q(k+1)=(x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}+(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}\leq 2^{\frac{-1}{n}}\quad (2)$$

So we have in fact :
$$Q(k+1)\Longrightarrow P(k-1)$$

Now the idea would be to put $k\longrightarrow \infty$ and $n\longrightarrow \infty$ such that $\frac{k}{n}=constant$ but I'm not sure if it's works!So I'm stuck here...

### Update 11/11/2020

We have on $x\in[0.15,0.5]$ and $1\leq k\leq n$ two naturals numbers with $n\geq 10^{10}$:

$$P(k)=(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}+x^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}\leq (1-x)^{(2x)}+x^{(2(1-x))}$$

So it seems here that we have a contradiction with :

$$Q(k+1)\Longrightarrow P(k-1)$$

Maybe we can exploit this to find a nice proof .

### My questions :

It is good (I have a doubt at the end)?

Are the irrational exponent covered ?

Thanks in advance

Max

[1] Vasile Cirtoaje, "Proofs of three open inequalities with power-exponential functions",
The Journal of Nonlinear Sciences and its Applications (2011), Volume: 4, Issue: 2, page 130-137.
https://eudml.org/doc/223938

Comment: @RiverLi It's one of the last step to prove the conjecture of Vasile Cirtoaje .Can you help me to find some mistakes ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: To the downvoter : why you do that ?  you make my efforts pointless !

Comment: Dear Erik Satie, I was not informed by your @. I will look at it soon. (+1) for your efforts.

Comment: What you did is: Given two integers $n, k$ with $1\le k\le n$,  
if $(x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}+(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}\leq 2^{\frac{-1}{n}}$ is true
for all $0.36\le x \le 0.5$,
then $(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}+x^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}\leq 1$ is also true for all $0.36\le x \le 0.5$.
However, the former is not true (e.g., $x = 0.5$), right?

Comment: @RiverLi I understand so we need to work with an $\epsilon_n$ such that at the end of the proof we have $(1-x)^{(2x)^{2}}+x^{(2(1-x))^{2}}\leq 2^{\frac{-1}{n}}$ for $0.36\leq x\leq \epsilon_n<0.5$ .With $\epsilon_n\longrightarrow 0.5$ as $n\longrightarrow \infty$

Comment: @RiverLi Do you see other mistake ?I shall open a bounty !Thanks

Comment: I think that if P(k) means $(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}+x^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}\leq 1$, then $P(k+1)$ means $(x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}+(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}\leq 1$ rather than $(x)^{(2(1-x))^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}+(1-x)^{(2x)^{1+\frac{k+1}{n}}}\leq 2^{\frac{-1}{n}}$, right?

Comment: @RiverLi yes the definition of $P(k)$ is incorrect .

Comment: @RiverLi my reasoning is ko...

Comment: @RiverLi Have you some idea to conclude the reasoning ?

Comment: It is fine till (0). I can not see if the idea after (0) helps. (2) is not true for $x = 1/2$. You said it works for $(0.36, 1/2 - \epsilon(n))$. You should go proceed.

Comment: @RiverLi I think that I have found a contradiction (see my update) are you agree ?

Comment: Please explain it in detail.